# Factory Girl Reserved Word Attributes for Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

The factory girl documentation advises using the add_attribute method to handle attributes that are reserved words, as follows:

```
factory :dna do
  add_attribute(:sequence) { 'GATTACA' }
end
```

However I have a model called Trait (which is reserved) and another model called ContestantTrait, which belongs to Trait. I've tried using add_attribute in varying ways to avoid the reserved word issue with the association, but none seem to work.

Any suggestions? These are the formats I've tried so far:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contestant_trait do
    add_attribute(:trait)
    add_attribute(:trait) {}
    add_attribute(:trait) {trait}
  end
end
```

Comment: You can alias the reserved word with a new name and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define an `:add_attribute` since `:trait` is an association. Use the keyword `association` as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contestant_trait do
    association :trait
    # ... other attributes
  end
end
```

As a side note, it is recommended to upgrade to `FactoryBot`:

> As of the 4.9.0 releases of both factory_girl and factory_girl_rails, both gems will be officially deprecated. In the 4.9.0 version.

See this post https://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory_bot for more in formation and how to upgrade.

Comment: have you able to solve your issue with above solution?